# Change $wp_query args before query is run on single template page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm running BeTheme but have added a custom post type. On index.php, I need to pull from both the regular Posts and the custom post type I created, "latest-news". I'm not sure how I can set it so that index.php pulls from both my Posts and my custom post type.

In my theme, index.php is pulling from a function from this template file, https://github.com/pingram3541/betheme/blob/master/includes/content-post.php

In the section starting on line 10 of this file:

```
if( ! function_exists('mfn_content_post') ){
function mfn_content_post( $query = false, $style = false, $images_only = false ){
    global $wp_query;
```

I'm pretty sure I need to change whatever `$args` variable `$wp_query` is pulling from so that `array('post_type' => array('post')` also has `'latest-news'` but I'm not sure where to find this, or if this is even the right approach at all.

EDIT:
I just tried adding the below code to `functions.php`:

```
function add_custom_post_type_to_query( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array('post', 'latest-news') );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_custom_post_type_to_query' );
```

And this did not work.

Comment: It is the right approach. Do you want your new query to search regular posts as well or only the custom post type?

Comment: Both. Ideally it would pull from both 'post' and 'latest-news' post types and sort by date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 21 of the file:

```
if( ! $query ) $query = $wp_query;
```

try editing it to

```
$args=[
'post_type' => ['post', 'latest-news'],
];
if( ! $query ) $query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Let me know if this works, depending on the time it might produce unexpected results.

Comment: That didn't work, it broke the site.

Inspired by your answer, I tried changing the line to:

`$args['post_type']='"post", "latest-news"';
  
if( ! $query ) $query = new WP_Query( $args );`

Which also didn't work, though it doesn't break the site, just makes it so that no posts display.

Comment: `I missed a semicolon after the ], try changing it to $args=['post_type' => ['post', 'latest-news']];` Let me know if this breaks the site or changes anything

Comment: That worked! Thanks! I should have caught that error as well, but I really appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped! It it solved you issue, please accept my answer, I would appreciate it. Good luck with the project!

Comment: Is this just changing the `'post_type'` value or the whole $args variable? Because when I go to, say, /category/category-name, it no longer only displays posts from that category but all posts.

(Not blaming you or anything, I should have been more clear in my question, since the answer you provided technically worked, but it just pointed out another issue I'll have to address)

Comment: In that case, the query is already set, give me a few minutes